# Installing iPhone app OTA through server

Tags: iphone, macos, app-store

Generally in order to test the iPhone app before going live in app store, we get the app file for iPhone and along with provisioning profile, we should be able to install the app in iPhone.

My query is "Is there a way to install the iPhone app over the air through server similar to Black berry?" If yes, how can it be done? Please let me know.

Thanks,
Naresh Krishna Kumar. K

Answer (score 3):

OTA distribution is a new [Enterprise](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/enterprise/) feature.  You will need an Enterprise account from Apple to do this.  With a normal account you can only do Ad Hoc and App Store distribution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the ans is "NO". Please make me correct if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Test Flight](http://testflightapp.com/). It allows you to upload ipa files and send a url to your beta testers where they can install it over the air (OTA).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see the following.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979-CH1-SW2