# How to install an iphone test app from a local server?

Tags: iphone, testing, installation

Something like a week or two ago I read an article (either from Stackoverflow, Mashable, HackerNews or some other tech site) which described how to upload an iphone app to one's server and then to install it directly to your iphone by navigating to the server's address or something like that. I remember the author mentioning that it was way easier than having the iphone plugged into the mac all the time to test the app. I don't remember the iphone needing to be jailbreaked or anything.

Does it ring any bell to anyone? I can't check my browser history since I had to reinstall my OS...

Comment: you can Google that! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245829/installing-iphone-app-ota-through-server

Comment: This post will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098290/ios-4-wireless-app-distribution-for-in-house-applications

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/) example uses php, but the HTML is transportable. Highly recommended. Note however that doing so might require an Enterprise Dev Center account (we used one for this).